# PhpAgi Dial: How to call a callback when callee answers the call

Tags: php, asterisk, agi

I'm using Asterisk to route calls. The logic of my application is rather complex, therefore I'm using PHPAGI.

I would like to execute **Dial** command and track several things:

1. Has the call been answered?
2. How many time it took for callee to answer the call?
3. How many time did take the talk?

All I have now is the **$agi->exec('Dial', ...)** function. The Dial command allows me to specify a macro, that is being called when the callee answers the call. But how can I specify any php callback instead of this? How can I track the answer moment in my phpagi script?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do macro like this

```
[macro-dial]
exten => s,1,System(/full/path/php_callback_on_answer.php ${ID})
```

For callback on hangup use h-extension or just parse cdrs in mysql.

You can record in variable time when call started and calculate time before answer.